# Shell usage of ":-" and advantage

Tags: shell, ksh

I found this line in a korn shell script:

```
var=${var:-/temp}
```

I am able to figure it out what it is doing

```
$ var=/data
$ var=${var:-/temp}
$ echo $var
/data
$ var=
$ echo $var

$ var=${var:-/temp}
$ echo $var
/temp
```

Does it have advantage over checking the value and then assigning?

Comment: Dubious advantage: it allows you to demonstrate your facial expression while you code: `:-/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s more streamlined;
you can do something in one simple command rather than two
(for example, `[[ -z $var ]]  &&  var=/temp`) or a complex command like

```
if [[ -z $var ]]
then
    var=/temp
fi
```

Also, it doesn’t require that the conditional value
be assigned to a variable.  For example,

```
#!/bin/sh
prog="$1"
# Do sanity checks & input validation here.
cc "$prog" -o "${2:-$(basename "$prog")}"
```

If this is invoked as `comp foo.c`,
it will compile `foo.c` and write the compiled output to `foo`. 
But `comp foo.c fu` will compile `foo.c`
and write the compiled output to `fu`.

This becomes especially significant
if you want to use multiple parameters with default values:

```
some_command ${1:-default_value1} ${2:-default_value2} ${3:-default_value3} ${4:-default_value4} ${5:-default_value5} ${6:-default_value6} ${7:-default_value7} ${8:-default_value8} ${9:-default_value9}
```

Doing this the other way would require some 18 commands
to set up the parameters.

Another example of how to use this
where you don’t need to assign the conditional value to a variable
is a script that wants to let the user edit a file:

```
#!/bin/sh
    ⋮ 
file=something
    ⋮ 
"$(EDITOR:-vi}" "$file"
```

which invokes the user’s favorite editor
(as specified through the `EDITOR` environment variable),
or `vi` if the user hasn’t specified one.

Answer (score 3):

It's a **compact idiom**. You can use it **inline** where commands are executed:

```
cmd "${arg1}" "${arg2}" "${arg3:-42}"
```

or at the start of the program (or as first statement in functions) to **assert the parameter interface** (using the `:` command):

```
: "${1:?} ${2:?}"
```

or check and assign it to the semantically named variables on which you operate in the program or resp. function:

```
foo=${1:?} bar=${2:?} baz=${3:-42}
```

where the first two arguments (in this example) are mandatory and the third one has a default value (above it's "42") if not provided.

You can also use the related constructs `${var:=val}` (or resp. `${var=val}`) for that purpose if not positional parameters but variables are involved:

```
: "${foo:=${1:?}} ${bar:=${2:?}} ${baz:=${3:-42}}"
```

The `${var:-42}` idiom has also a variant `${var-42}` (i.e. without the `:` colon) to **differentiate** *unset* parameters from *empty* parameters; `test` constructs can not directly differentiate *empty* variables from *unset* variables.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between `-` and `:-`.  Since the question wasn’t even about `:?`, you should probably explain it too.  Also, even after looking it up in `bash(1)`, I don’t understand quite what you’re trying to illustrate with your `: ${arg1:?} ${arg2:?} ${arg3:-default}` line.  Is this meant to be done *after* doing `arg1="$1"` and `arg2="$2"`?  Wouldn’t it be simpler to say `arg1="${1:?}"` and `arg2="${2:?}"`?  And what does `: … ${arg3:-default}` accomplish?

Comment: Hi @G-Man! - The question was also about "advantage over checking the value and then assigning" so I showed the `${var:-val }` together with `${var-val}`, because the `[...]` or `test` does not support that differentiation. Because of the "verify interface" pattern that I illustrated as a coding idiom I used `${var:?}` (or `${var?}`) as well, since that is in practise typically part of that pattern. Your latter point is valid; it's a typo that stems from the copy/paste from preceding example; I've fixed that. And the final "default" is just a sample value; I could have also used `${3:-42}`.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas; Thanks for inspecting my answer. But why would quotes be necessary in this case? I certainly wouldn't have thought so.

Answer (score 3):

There are three cases: `var` might have been initially unset, empty, or non-empty. In the first two cases, it's set to `/temp`; in the last case it's left alone.

Another way to do the same thing is

```
: "${var:=/temp}"
```

I prefer that one because the chain of assignments is clearer, but it's a matter of aesthetics.

Under normal settings, this is equivalent to

```
if [ -z "$var" ]; then var="/temp"; fi
```

which is arguably clearer. However, the syntax `${var:-…}` or `${var:=…}` has an advantage: it works even under `set -u`, which causes `$var` to error out if `var` is unset. The advantage of `set -u` is that it makes it easy to catch mistakes due to mistyping the name of a variable or forgetting to define it under certain conditions. However, it can only be used with scripts that don't assume that expanding an unset variable is always possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "overcheck" - it is "default value", in other word if value is not set (or empty) use default value.

Comment: I don’t think he was treating “overcheck” as a word (or even an atomic concept); I think he was asking “Does technique A (using `var=${var:-/temp}` have an advantage over technique B (checking the value with some sort of `[ … ]` or `[[…]]` test and then assigning the new value conditionally)?”